# How do I pass int arguments in RequestParams?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to use int arguments (matchID, typeID and live) in params, but they seem to be missing from the final query string obtained with params.toString(). What am I missing here?

```
        RequestParams params = new RequestParams();

        String email = user.getEmail();
        params.put("email", email);
        params.put("password", user.getPassword());
        params.put("token", TextUtil.getToken(email));
        params.put("live", live);
        params.put("matchID", matchID);
        params.put("typeID", typeID);
        params.put("quote", quote);
        params.put("comment", comment);

        System.out.println("matchID: " + matchID); // matchID: 1
        System.out.println("typeID: " + typeID); // typeID : 2
        System.out.println("params: " + params.toString()); // params: quote=2&token=XXX&comment=&email=mail@mail.com&password=mypw
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem fixed. `put` only allows String values. Casting the integer values to Strings worked fine.

```
        params.put("live", String.valueOf(live));
        params.put("matchID", String.valueOf(matchID));
        params.put("typeID", String.valueOf(typeID));
```